# file upload http header help or example java

Tags: java, http, file-upload, http-headers, webserver

Okay so i am working on a special little project and i require some help. I have started working on a Java webserver written using only java libraries. The aim is to be the simplest webserver written in java around. I have been very successful lately, but recently i have run into a problem with uploading files to the server. The server recieves the headers but i can not see the text from inside the file. Any help would be great! Thank you

you can see the website hosted by the webserver here: [blends.hopto.org/beta](http://blends.hopto.org/beta)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out the file was just written after a newline feed

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems could be due to missing enctype="multipart/form-data" in the form that is submitted. Also in the servlet side this article was helpful while I did a file upload to the server: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glrbb.html